# Using 'resource' route in rails 3.1.0.rc4 (Newbie)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I understood how simple route, default route and root routes are used. But I didn't get a hair of what resource routes do and how it works. A lot of examples out there assume that one has worked with rails 2 before. So here is my situation:

I created a controller + view like this: $ rails g controller main view1 view2 view3 ... viewN

Now I set root :to => "main#view1" and others are by default given routes like GET "/main/view2" etc. Can I use the concept of "resources" in here? If not then where is it used?

Comment: why don't you accept any of the answers given to all your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resources` are used for basic CRUD routes as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

Other routes need to be explicitly written (but you'd better nest them in a namespace).

Comment: I did read the RoR guide. The terms like HTML verbs, CRUD etc. increase my cognitive overload and I don't understand what it means. You see, I am moving away from photoshop and getting into programming. So probably an explanation w.r.t my rails g controller Main view1 view2 view3 will be better. I do understand CRUD, but I am yet to create a Model in my first app.

Comment: Does using resources with HTML verbs mean if view1 = show_article, view2 = edit_form (with post request), view 3 = something else... then the control main = resource and all the actions are mapped accordingly?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for making me notice. I have accepted your answer already.